# GWT compilation on the fly

Tags: java, gwt, compiler-construction

Is there a way to run Google Web Toolkit compiler directly from Java code to compile the source code made on the fly? In the same manner as javax.tools for example.

Comment: I'm not sure, but maybe Vaadin framework uses GWT in this way. If someone have expirience with Vaadin, could you explain details of integration GWT to Vaadin?

Answer (score 1):

GWT compiles all sources at once, because it compiles the result in one file and performs a lot of optimizations, like leaving out methods not used and inline methods to minimize the total size of the JavaScript file generated. A compilation step is therefor takes some time, so compilation on the fly would not be a workable solution.

Comment: Thanks for your response!

Actually I'm working on IDE for GWT applications. Therefore compilation time is not important, but the able to running the GWT Compiler without command-line execution and XML configurations will be useful.

Answer (score 1):

I think so: `com.google.gwt.dev.Compiler` has a `main` method. Either call that method directly, or look into its code, and you should be able to build the `CompilerOptions` etc. yourself.

When you create a GWT project using `webAppCreator`, you get a `build.xml` with a `gwtc` target. This should help you with the classpath and the arguments you need to run the compiler.